# Azure perf counters not showing up in logs

Tags: performance, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I recently created custom performance counters in Azure however when i check the my tools (i used Cerebrata and Quest tools) or WAD Performance Counter tables I can't see them.

However when i use remote login to my Azure instance I can see them.

Can anyone give a suggesstion as to why this is so?

Answer (score 0):

In order to see custom counters, you have to use them.  Can you confirm that in addition to installing the counters, you have also created and used the counters somewhere in code?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a very dumb question, but have you added the new counters to the list of counters that are being captured by the diagnostics and have you configured those counters to be 'pushed' to storage?

Using the DiagnosticsMonitorConfiguration PerformanceCounters collection?

If you have not, and you have any questions on how to set this up let me know.

Comment: I did add them using the tools - but no values show up even though they are setup to increment

and they are configured to storage, but I don't see them when i query the table

However, I see changes when i use the remote login to the server and check the event logs and monitoring